# Comma separated string to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server, I have a table. The `id` column is the primary key. I am sending several `id` values as a comma-separated string into the stored procedure (eg: `1,2,3,4`). I need to update two columns to string value 'A'. Can anyone please give me an example how to handle those multiple values inside the stored procedure?

Comment: If your database compatibility level is not lower than 130, then use `SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(id,',')`

Comment: @Pream:only if he is using SQLServer 2016

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways. It could be one of the following.

```
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET ColumnA = 'A'
WHERE 
    ',' + '1,2,3,4' + ',' LIKE '%,' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(100)) + ',%'
```

You can do it with [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the update in a string, and then execute it:

```
declare @myQuery as char(100) = 'update myTable set ColumnA = ''A'', ColumnB = ''A'' where Id in (' + @myParameterString +')'
execute(@myQuery)
```

Note: to escape single quotes in T-SQL you have to type two single quotes (in ''A'', for example).